# What is the longest string that would convert to a valid DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, data-cleaning, date-formatting

I am writing a data parser and trying to work out if a field is a number, a date, a string etc.

The .NET `DateTime.TryParse` is understandably slow when checking many records (as it checks many different date formats). Therefore, I want to shortcut the processing if possible. A simple check I can do initially is look at the length of the string and reject it if it falls outside of some bounds.

The shortest date I think I should reasonably expect is 6 characters long (e.g. d/M/yy) so I can make the following check:

```
if (fieldValue.Length < 6)
{
    // no datetime is shorter than 6 chars (e.g. d/M/yy is the shotest I can think of)
    return false;
}
```

**What is the longest string that still represents a parse-able DateTime?**

(For example, "Wednesday, 30th September 2020 12:34:56" is pretty long but I bet there are longer examples!)

A few points:

- I am not looking for tricksy answers where the date is padded out with white space or something like that.
- I am focused on English dates initially but would be interested if other cultures can throw up longer examples.

Comment: Don't you think that `DateTime.TryParse` _also_ implements these assertions, like checking the minimum length of a string before it can be a valid date? Perhaps you'd actually be adding to the processing time.

Comment: That's a good point, Alexander. I wonder if someone can confirm?

Comment: You may want to consider that if you know you only have a few exact formats of DateTime, just check those formats via [TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: I would argue that the longest _possible_ date string is much longer than the vast  majority of _practical_ string/numeric values.

Comment: @MarkRobinson If you're really interested, here's the [reference source for the parser](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs). If you look at `GetRegularToken`, you'll see when it finds a digit it will keep collecting subsequent digits. So if you have a really long string containing only digits, it'll try to consume the whole string.  The same with letters (under `DateFormatInfo.Tokenize`).

Comment: Wow! 5,000 + lines of code. I scanned it though and couldn't find any length checks so I guess @Alexander van Oostenrijk it looks like they don't implement these length assertions. Just shows how complex date parsing is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the longest string that still represents a parse-able
>   DateTime?

Take a look at the list of [custom format specifiers for a DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), and take all of those into account.

For instance, this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string strNow = dt.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy gg hh:mm:ss.fffffff tt K");
Console.WriteLine(strNow);
```

Gives:

```
Tuesday, June 16, 2020 A.D. 08:47:02.2667911 AM -06:00
```

But those different types of values can be output differently based on the information in the DateTime.  Look CLOSELY at all the different possible outputs for each specifier in the documentation to see what I mean.

Comment: So probably something like:
Wednesday, September 16, 2020 A.D. 08:47:02.2667911 AM -06:00

... which it 61 characters long.